# HotChocolate.SchemaException: For more details look at the `Errors` property

Tags: .net-core, graphql

HotChocolate.SchemaException: For more details look at the `Errors` property.

1. Unable to infer or resolve a schema type from the type reference `Input: IAuthorizationService`.
2. Unable to infer or resolve a schema type from the type reference `Input: IProjectsRepository`.
3. Unable to infer or resolve a schema type from the type reference `Input: ISpecificationsRepository`.

I should get result without error. Getting 500 instead of 200 status